# How do I get my custom header template rule to pass it's output downstream cc_binary/cc_library dependency?

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to build a rule for bazel which emulates the CMake *.in template system.

This has two challenges, the first is generate the template output. The second is make the output available to both `genrules`, `filegroups` and `cc_*` rules. The third is to get that dependency to transitively be passed to further downstream rules.

I have it generating the output file `version.hpp` in genfiles (or bazel-bin), and I can get the initial library rule to include it, but I can't seem to figure out how to make my cc_binary rule, which depends on the cc_library and transitively the header_template rule to find the header file.

I have the following .bzl rule:

```py
def _header_template_impl(ctx):
    # this generates the output from the template
    ctx.actions.expand_template(
        template = ctx.file.template,
        output = ctx.outputs.out,
        substitutions = ctx.attr.vars,
    )

    return [
            # create a provider which says that this
            # out file should be made available as a header
            CcInfo(compilation_context=cc_common.create_compilation_context(
                headers=depset([ctx.outputs.out])
            )),

            # Also create a provider referencing this header ???
            DefaultInfo(files=depset(
                [ctx.outputs.out]
            ))
        ]

header_template = rule(
    implementation = _header_template_impl,
    attrs = {
        "vars": attr.string_dict(
            mandatory = True
        ),
        "extension": attr.string(default=".hpp"),
        "template": attr.label(
            mandatory = True,
            allow_single_file = True,
        ),
    },
    outputs = {
        "out": "%{name}%{extension}",
    },
    output_to_genfiles = True,
)
```

elsewhere I have a cc_library rule:

```py
load("//:tools/header_template.bzl", "header_template")

# version control
BONSAI_MAJOR_VERSION = '2'
BONSAI_MINOR_VERSION = '0'
BONSAI_PATCH_VERSION = '9'
BONSAI_VERSION = \
    BONSAI_MAJOR_VERSION + '.' + \
    BONSAI_MINOR_VERSION + '.' + \
    BONSAI_PATCH_VERSION

header_template(
    name = "bonsai_version",
    extension = ".hpp",
    template = "version.hpp.in",
    vars = {
        "@BONSAI_MAJOR_VERSION@": BONSAI_MAJOR_VERSION,
        "@BONSAI_MINOR_VERSION@": BONSAI_MINOR_VERSION,
        "@BONSAI_PATCH_VERSION@": BONSAI_PATCH_VERSION,
        "@BONSAI_VERSION@": BONSAI_VERSION,
    },
)

# ...

private = glob([
        "src/**/*.hpp",
        "src/**/*.cpp",
        "proto/**/*.hpp",
    ])
public = glob([
        "include/*.hpp",
        ":bonsai_version",
    ])

cc_library(
    # target name matches directory name so you can call:
    #  bazel build .
    name = "bonsai",
    srcs = private,
    hdrs = public,
    # public headers
    includes = [
        "include",
    ],

    # ...

    deps = [
        ":bonsai_version",
        # ...
    ],

    # ...
)
```

When I build, my source files need to be able to:

```cpp
#include "bonsai_version.hpp"
```

I think the answer involves `CcInfo` but I'm grasping in the dark as to how it should be constructed.

I've already tried add `"-I$(GENDIR)/" + package_name()` to the copts, to no avail. The generated header still isn't available.

My expectation is that I should be able to return some kind of Info object that would allow me to add the dependency in `srcs`. Maybe it should be a `DefaultInfo`.

I've dug through the bazel rules examples and the source, but I'm missing something fundamental, and I can't find documentation that discuss this particular.

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```py
header_template(
    name = "some_header",
    extension = ".hpp",
    template = "some_header.hpp.in",
    vars = {
        "@SOMEVAR@": "value",
        "{ANOTHERVAR}": "another_value",
    },
)

cc_library(
   name = "foo",
   srcs = ["foo.src", ":some_header"],
   ...
)

cc_binary(
   name = "bar",
   srcs = ["bar.cpp"],
   deps = [":foo"],
)
```

and include the generated header like so:

```cpp
#include "some_header.hpp"

void bar(){
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer looks like it is:

```
def _header_template_impl(ctx):
    # this generates the output from the template
    ctx.actions.expand_template(
        template = ctx.file.template,
        output = ctx.outputs.out,
        substitutions = ctx.attr.vars,
    )

    return [
            # create a provider which says that this
            # out file should be made available as a header
            CcInfo(compilation_context=cc_common.create_compilation_context(

                # pass out the include path for finding this header
                includes=depset([ctx.outputs.out.dirname]),

                # and the actual header here.
                headers=depset([ctx.outputs.out])
            ))
        ]
```

elsewhere:

```
header_template(
    name = "some_header",
    extension = ".hpp",
    template = "some_header.hpp.in",
    vars = {
        "@SOMEVAR@": "value",
        "{ANOTHERVAR}": "another_value",
    },
)

cc_library(
   name = "foo",
   srcs = ["foo.cpp"],
   deps = [":some_header"],
   ...
)

cc_binary(
   name = "bar",
   srcs = ["bar.cpp"],
   deps = [":foo"],
)
```

Comment: This worked for me! Is there a way to include a prefix so that the generate header can be accessed like: `#include "my_custom_prefix/some_header.hpp"`

Answer (score 0):

If your header has a generic name (eg config.h) and you want it to be private (ie `srcs` instead of `hdrs`), you might need a different approach. I've seen this problem for gflags, which "leaked" config.h and affected libraries that depended on it ([issue](https://github.com/gflags/gflags/issues/233)).

Of course, in both cases, the easiest solution is to generate and commit header files for the platforms you target.

Alternatively, you can set `copts` for the `cc_library` rule that uses the generated private header:

```
cc_library(
   name = "foo",
   srcs = ["foo.cpp", "some_header.hpp"],
   copts = ["-I$(GENDIR)/my/package/name"],
   ...
)
```

If you want this to work when your repository is included as an external repository, you have a bit more work cut out for you due to [bazel issue #4463](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4463).

PS. You might want to see if [cc_fix_config](https://github.com/antonovvk/bazel_rules/blob/b3813bf2cb89f174f926984c68d15917db16916c/examples/config/BUILD#L34) from https://github.com/antonovvk/bazel_rules works for you. It's just a wrapper around perl but I found it useful.

Comment: it's a public header, so that behavior was desired, but I suppose I could add an option that would move the inclusion in the rule for public/private.

for whatever reason, the GENDIR trick wasn't working for me. routing around genfile directories is fraught because I don't think the header gets generated when the template changes.

Comment: If your library has a dependency on some_header.hpp and the file doesn't exist in the source tree, Bazel *should* ensure it's up-to-date before building the library, but maybe there's some weirdness or bug in play. However, if using CcInfo works for your case then it's certainly less error-prone than messing around with copts and GENDIR.